Hemp upgrade: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: did not find expected key
I just created a new Helm chart but when I run helm upgrade I get:
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on /templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 38: did not find expected key
And this is my Yaml file:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
      namespace:  {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
      labels:
        chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
    spec:
      {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
      replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
      {{- end }}
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: {{ .Values.service.name}}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
            image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
            imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
            ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /health
                port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
              initialDelaySeconds: 2
              periodSeconds: 30
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /health
                port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
              initialDelaySeconds: 2
              periodSeconds: 30
            resources:
      {{- $r := .Values.resources }}
      {{ .Values.nonprod | default false | ternary $r.nonprod $r.prod | toYaml | indent 10 }}
      {{- if .Values.nonprod }}
              limits:
                cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.cpu }}
                memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.memory }}
              requests:
                cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.cpu }}
                memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
      {{- else }}
              limits:
                cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.cpu }}
                memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.memory }}
              requests:
                cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.cpu }}
                memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.memory }}
      {{- end }}    
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /root/tls.crt
                name: conjurconfig
                subPath: tls.crt
              - mountPath: /root/tls.key
                name: conjurconfig
                subPath: tls.key
          volumes:
           - name: config
            secret:
              secretName: config
          imagePullSecrets:
             - name: default-image-pull-secret

And this is my values.yaml file
metadata:
      name: api
      namespace: trans
    deployment:
      replicaCount: 3
    image:
      repository: registry.rancher.abc.com/capture_trans/transactionapi
      tag: 0.0.11
      pullPolicy: Always
    service:
      name: transactionapi 
      type: ClusterIP
      externalPort: 4545
      internalPort: 4545
    resources: 
      nonprod:
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 300Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 400m
          memory: 200Mi
      prod:
        limits:
          cpu: 800m
          memory: 1000Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 800m
          memory: 1000Mi    
    ingress:
      env: dev-rancher
      domain: abc.com
    autoscaling:
      enabled: true
      minReplicas: 3
      maxReplicas: 5
      targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80

Unable to figure out. Tried yamllint. Any help is much appreciated.

I'd try running helm template --debug and looking for the thing that visually looks wrong.  It's low-tech and you can get a lot of output, but it does work.
